# Produce a PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to find the best way to produce the following table in a report (rdlc) -

[image: Desired pivot table required]

This is showing the teacher name on the far left column (pulled from a teachers table), then bookings from Monday to Friday (pulled from a bookingdays table). In the rows, an AM booking (BookingDuration: 0) will be in the top row, a PM booking (BookingDuration: 1) will be in the bottom row and finally a Full Day (BookingDuration: 2) will be in the top row but in upper case (dealt with in the RDLC).

The problem I am having is producing a table from SQL that is speedy and tidy. I believe I need to produce a PIVOT table, however I have tried many different methods.

There is also hourly bookings to consider (BookingDuration: 3). Each booking day has a start and end time. so if the start time is < 12:00 and the end time is > 12:00, full day. If start and end time < 12:00 then AM and finally if the end time and start time > 12:00, Full day. There may also be 2x AM hourly bookings (09:00- 10:00 and 10:30 - 11:30) but never more than 2. The same applies to PM. When this happens, the first AM will be in the top box and the second AM will be in the bottom box. I have been assured that 2x AM and 1x PM booking will never occur, so I have added validation in the create booking form to prevent this.

There is a row for every teacher. When a teacher has no bookings, the teacher will still be shown on the report but the values will be empty.

My table (BookingDays) is as follows -

```
ID - INT(PK)
BookingID - INT
BookingDate - date
DayText - VARCHAR(50)
StartTIme - decimal
EndTime - decimal
TeacherID int
BookingDuration - int
NoOfHours - decimal
TotalChargeAmount - decimal
TotalPayAmount - decimal
Status - int
```

There is also a teachers table containing Full name etc. This is joined to the BookingDays table by the TeacherID column.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

This is what I have tried so far (showing only Friday due to text limit). The problem with this one is I can't get the AM/PM hourly's showing if there is 2 -

```
with CTE_D as 
        ( 
            SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,CONVERT(date, @WeekStart, 103)), 0) as BookingDate 

            union all 

            select DATEADD(day, 1, BookingDate) 
            from CTE_D where BookingDate < DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,CONVERT(date, @WeekStart, 103)), 6)
        )
        SELECT 
            t.Firstname, 
            t.Surname, t.Telephone, t.Mobile, t.Band, tb.Band, t.DefaultChargeRateDaily as 'TeacherDefaultChargeRateDaily', t.DefaultPayRateDaily as 'TeacherDefaultPayRateDaily', t.DefaultChargeRateAM, t.DefaultChargeRatePM, t.DefaultChargeRateDaily, t.DefaultPayRateAM, t.DefaultPayRatePM, t.DefaultPayRateDaily,
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 0 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayAM",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 0 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayAMTotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 0 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayAMTotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 0 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayAMBandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 1 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayPM", 
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 1 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayPMTotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 1 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayPMTotalPayAmount",           
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 1 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayPMBandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 2 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayDaily",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 2 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayDailyTotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 2 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayDailyTotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingType = 0 and bd.BookingDuration = 2 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayDailyBandBookedAt",

            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID END) as "FridayHourlyAMCount",    
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM",                 
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAMSchoolName",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAMTimes",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAMTotalChargeAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAMTotalPayAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAMBandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2",                    
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2SchoolName",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2Times",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2TotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2TotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) < CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') AND bd.NoOfHOurs < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyAM2BandBookedAt",

            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID END) as "FridayHourlyPMCount",   
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM",                            
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPMSchoolName",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPMTimes",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPMTotalChargeAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPMTotalPayAmount",
            MAX(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPMBandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2",                           
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2SchoolName",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2Times",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2TotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2TotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and CONVERT(time(0), bd.StartTime) >= CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') and bd.NoOfHours < 5.5 AND s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyPM2BandBookedAt",

            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyFullDay",             
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN s.SchoolName ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyFullDaySchoolName",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, bd.StartTime, 100), 7)) + '-' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), bd.EndTime, 100), 7)), 'AM',''), 'PM', '') ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyFullDayTimes",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN bd.TotalChargeAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyFullDayTotalChargeAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN bd.TotalPayAmount ELSE NULL END) "FridayHourlyFullDayTotalPayAmount",
            MIN(CASE WHEN bd.DayText = 'Friday' and bd.BookingDuration = 3 and bd.NoOfHours >= 5.5 and s.PrimarySchool = 1 AND CONVERT(time(0), bd.EndTime) > CONVERT(time(0), '12:00:00') THEN bd.BandBookedAt ELSE NULL END) "FridayFullDayBandBookedAt",
            COUNT(CASE WHEN s.PrimarySchool = 1 THEN bd.ID ELSE NULL END) "BookingCount",
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            t.Notes, t.DefaultChargeRateDaily, t.DefaultPayRateDaily 
                FROM Teachers t 
                cross join CTE_D d 
                inner join TeacherBands tb 
                    on t.Band = tb.ID
                left join BookingDays bd 
                    on t.ID = bd.TeacherID and 
                        bd.BookingDate = d.BookingDate and bd.BookingType = 0
                left join BookingDurations bds 
                    on bd.BookingDuration = bds.ID 
                left join BookingTypes bt
                    on bd.BookingType = bt.ID
                left join Bookings b 
                    on bd.BookingID = b.ID
                left join Schools s 
                    on b.School = s.ID and s.PrimarySchool = 1
                    WHERE Active = 0 and (bd.Status = 0 or bd.Status IS NULL) and (t.Status != 2) and t.PrimarySchool = 1
                GROUP BY Firstname, Surname, t.Telephone, t.Mobile, t.Notes, t.Band, tb.Band, t.DefaultPayRateDaily, t.DefaultChargeRateDaily, t.DefaultChargeRateAM, t.DefaultChargeRatePM, t.DefaultChargeRateDaily, t.DefaultPayRateAM, t.DefaultPayRatePM, t.DefaultPayRateDaily
                ORDER BY Surname, Firstname ASC
```

Hope this makes sense. I have tried to adapt a pivot table I have used previously, however to no avail. I can't seem to get the school name displayed when it outputs to the final columns.

```
    WITH Bookings AS
(  SELECT  TeacherID,
            [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, BookingDate),
            [0], [1], [2], [3],
            [Status] = CASE 
                            WHEN ([0] > 0 AND [1] > 0) THEN 'XXX'
                            WHEN [2] > 0 THEN 'XXX'  
                            WHEN [0] > 0 THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [1] > 0 THEN 'AM'  
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') AND EndTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'XXX'   
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND EndTime <= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'PM'
                            WHEN [3] > 0 AND StartTime >= CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00') THEN 'AM'                     

                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  TeacherID, 
                        BookingDate, 
                        BookingDuration, 
                        StartTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MIN(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,
                        EndTime = CASE WHEN BookingDuration = 3 THEN CAST(MAX(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID, BookingDate, BookingDuration) AS TIME) ELSE NULL END,                        
                        [x] = 1
                FROM    BookingDays bd
                WHERE   (Status = 0 OR Status IS NULL)
            ) BookingDays
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(x)
                FOR BookingDuration IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
            ) pvt

             WHERE BookingDate >= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND BookingDate <= DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 6)

), PivotedBookings AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    Bookings
            PIVOT
            (   MAX([Status])
                FOR [WeekDay] IN ([MondayAM1], [MondayAM2], [MondayPM1], [MondayPM2], [MondayFullDay])
            ) pvt

)
SELECT ID,Firstname,Surname,Band,'£' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DefaultChargeRateDaily) + '/' + '£' + CONVERT(varchar(50), DefaultPayRateDaily) as 'BandRates',Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,MAX(MondayAM1) MondayAM1,MAX(MondayAM2) MondayAM2,MAX(MondayPM1) MondayPM1,MAX(MondayPM2) MondayPM2,MAX(MondayFullDay) MondayFullDay, Notes
  FROM (
SELECT  t.ID, 
        t.Firstname, 
        t.Surname, 
        tb.Band,
        t.DefaultChargeRateDaily,
        t.DefaultPayRateDaily,
        t.Telephone,
        t.Mobile,
        t.Teacher,
        t.TeacherAssistant,
        CASE WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' END + ' - ' + CASE WHEN t.ALevel > 0 THEN 'ALevel' WHEN t.Year11 > 0 THEN 'Y11' WHEN t.Year10 > 0 THEN 'Y10' WHEN t.Year9 > 0 THEN 'Y9' WHEN t.Year8 > 0 THEN 'Y8' WHEN t.Year7 > 0 THEN 'Y7' WHEN t.Year6 > 0 THEN 'Y6' WHEN t.Year5 > 0 THEN 'Y5' WHEN t.Year4 > 0 THEN 'Y4' WHEN t.Year3 > 0 THEN 'Y3' WHEN t.Year2 > 0 THEN 'Y2' WHEN t.Year1 > 0 THEN 'Y1' WHEN t.Reception > 0 THEN 'REC' WHEN t.Nursery > 0 THEN 'NUR' ELSE '' END as 'KeyStage',

        MondayAM1 = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.MondayAM1, '') END,
        MondayAM2 = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.MondayAM2, '') END,
        MondayPM1 = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.MondayPM1, '') END,
        MondayPM2 = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.MondayPM2, '') END,
        MondayFullDay = CASE WHEN an.Date = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'06/17/2013'), 0) AND an.TeacherID = t.ID THEN an.Text WHEN t.Status = 0 THEN 'XXX'  ELSE COALESCE(pb.MondayFullDay, '') END,
        Notes
FROM    Teachers t

        LEFT JOIN PivotedBookings pb
            ON pb.TeacherID = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN TeacherBands tb
            ON tb.ID = t.Band
        LEFT JOIN AvailabilityNotes an 
            ON t.ID = an.TeacherID
            WHERE t.Active = 0 and (t.Status = 1 or t.Status = 0) and t.PrimarySchool = 1
            ) T1
 GROUP BY ID,Firstname,Surname,Telephone,Mobile,Teacher,TeacherAssistant,KeyStage,Notes,DefaultChargeRateDaily,DefaultPayRateDaily,Band
 ORDER BY Surname,Firstname asc
```

Comment: Have you considered using [the pivot table feature in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: Does your output only have one row? If so you don't need to pivot.

Comment: The output will have one row per teacher, but roughly 200 odd rows, one for each teacher

Comment: I have modified my question to include my PIVOT table attempt. I can't seem to get it to show the school name on the output columns. Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with your tables and some sample data?